# Align Text to the bottom of the box

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox

I was wondering if anyone can help me align content to the bottom of the box.

I want to keep everything uniform and tidy.  I want the author, date and thumbnail (please see highlighted screenshot) all to be level at the bottom of the box. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6W3k.png)

here is the link to the page
[2](https://plateandpalette.ie/blog/)

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
    .eael-entry-footer
```

this needs to go at the bottom

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `min-height` to `.eael-entry-title`

```
.eael-entry-title { min-height: 85px }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Richa!! I was taking ages trying to do via flexbox.. Appreciate your help that worked great.